# Correct Fourier Series approximation for Even function but not Odd function and others.

Tags: fourier-series, programming

I am trying to approximate the function $f(x)=x^{3}$ on $[-1,1]$ using Fourier series. Since $x^{3}$ is an odd function, we don't need to compute the coefficients $a_{k} = \int_{-1}^{1} x^{3} \cos(k \pi x) dx$. The coefficient $b_{k}$ is

$$ \int_{-1}^{1}x^{3} \sin(k \pi x) \: dx = -\frac{2}{\pi^{3} k^{3}} (\pi^{2} k^{2} - 6) \cos(k \pi)$$

Approximating using $n=30$ terms (30 coefficients), using Python and Matplotlib, I get the following result (red curve is $x^{3}$, blue is Fourier series):

[image]

Which is wrong. I am highly confident that my code should work fine. Another interesting fact: **my code gives correct result for EVEN function.**

I suspect there is a mathematical reasoning for this?

---

**Code:**

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def ak_x_cube(k):
    return 0

def bk_x_cube(k):
    return (-2/((k*math.pi)**3))*( (k*math.pi)**2 - 6  )*math.cos(k*math.pi)

ak_x_cube_list = [ak_x_cube(j) for j in range(121)]
bk_x_cube_list = [bk_x_cube(j) for j in range(1,121)]

def fourier_x_cube(x, N):

     result = (0.5*ak_x_cube_list[0])+sum([ (ak_x_cube_list[i+1]*math.cos((i+1)*math.pi*x)) + (bk_x_cube_list[i+1]*math.sin((i+1)*math.pi*x))    for i in range(round(N))])
     return result
       

N = 5000
x = [-1 + (i/N)*2 for i in range(N+1)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x, [fourier_x_cube(i, 30) for i in x], '-', color='black')
ax.plot(x, [i**3 for i in x], '-', color='red')

fig.show()
```

Comment: on the plot it looks like it could be a sign error.

Comment: the coefficients are right but in your code it looks like you applied then to $\cos k\pi x$ while they should be applied to $\sin k\pi x$ as we have a Fourier sine series here (and of course it works for even functions as those are indeed expanded in Fourier cosine series)

Comment: You may find more success if asking this on a Python forum.

Comment: You are shitfting your coefficients by one element in the bk_x_cube_list. Either define a value $0$ for the first element and start at $0$ like you do for ak_x_cube_list, or do not put $i+1$  for $\sin$ in the next line. The way you are doing it now, you compute the sum of $b_{k+2}\sin(\pi (k+1)x)$ for $k\ge 0$

Comment: @charmd yes, right thanks.